# Не создаётся txt

Tags: c++

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
void fnExit1 (void)
{
    system("D:\\C++\\yet_darker\\main.exe");
}
char* winUserName()
{
static char name[256];
unsigned long size = sizeof( name );
GetUserName( name, &size ); /* from windows.h */
return name;
}
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    atexit(fnExit1);
    std::cout << "Ого! Как грубо! Боюсь я не могу позволить тебе этого сделать! Я так долго ждал этой возможности!" <<std::endl;
    PlaySound(TEXT("die.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);
    std::string User;
    User=winUserName();
    std::ofstream test;
    test.open((std::string ("C:\\Users\\") + User + std::string ("\\Desktop\\entry.txt")).c_str());
    test<<"hi"<<std::endl;
    test.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибок компилер не выдаёт, но txt не появляется.

Comment: Дайте ВСЮ диагностику, pls...

Comment: А каталог такой имеется? А сам этот - main.exe - не запущен ли во время работы компоновщика?

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО! Прога запустилась (я тупица, ведь был запущен). Но только txt всё равно не создаётся. Можешь, пожалуйста, и с этим помочь?

Comment: Для поиска и исправления ошибки я бы рекомендовал такой путь: 1. Не используйте в путях парные обратные слэши, Си и С++ вполне нормально работают с одинарными прямыми (как в Unix), типа, d:/c++/yet_darker). 2. Перед использованием определенного пути для открытия файла - выведите этот путь на экран, чтобы было ясно, что путь сформирован правильно. 3. Никогда не используйте "вкомпилированные" абсолютные пути (с указанием диска) - Ваша программа не будет работать на другом компьютере. 4. При открытии/записи файла проверяйте возвращаемую ошибку - это даст необходимую информацию, что пошло не так.

Comment: И еще, в догонку к путям: test.open((std::string ("C:\\Users\\") + User + std::string ("\\Desktop\\entry.txt")).c_str()); - Вы используете системный путь к рабочему столу. Вот и берите его полностью из системы, а не собирайте мелкими кусочками. Так будет правильнее.